# Xamarin Mac display Popup

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am creating a Xamarin Mac application.
How can I display a Popup View in Xamarin iOS application. Only few samples are there for Xamarin iOS platform.

Comment: Lots of Xamarin.Mac samples in their GitHub repo, here is one on dialogs: https://github.com/xamarin/mac-samples/tree/master/MacDialog

Comment: If you refer to alerts/messageboxes, they are there on @SushiHangover link. If you refer to something else like a box that popsup and can be light dismissed, there isn't such thing out of box on macOS so it requires some work to be made, but whatever native developers can do you can do it too...

Comment: Xamarin.iOS or  Xamarin.Mac?